# Validations controls are not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, asp.net-validators

i am using visual studio 2012 on windows 10. When i use a validation in web form it shows a validation has been added (in design view), but when i open in browser it doesn't show anything. HELP

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

    void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
       Label1.Text = "VALID NUMBER!";
    }

</script>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function validateNumber(oSrc, args) {
           args.IsValid = (args.Value % 5 == 0);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <p>
            Number: 
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" 
             runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             &nbsp;
            <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" 
             runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
             ErrorMessage="Number must be divisible by 5" 
             ClientValidationFunction="validateNumber">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button id="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" 
             runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the `Text` attribute of the `CustomValidator` to see a mark when the validation fails:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Text="*" ... />
```

In order to see the error message, you should add a `ValidationSummary` in your form:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" />
```

Finally, in your `validateNumber` function, you should convert the `Value` argument to a number before testing it:

```
var value = parseInt(args.Value);
```